# Can the constant be a complex number in wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> Solving the Wave equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$

If I apply separation of variables, with $u(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$, then we find

$$\frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{g''(t)}{g(t)}=k$$

Can $k$ be a complex number here? I read somewhere for the heat equation it is not possible (so it must be real). Is it valid for the wave equation?

Comment: To truly understand what you are doing, I would suggest solving the corresponding ODEs

$$f'' = kf, \quad g'' = kg$$

for $k<0$, $k=0$, $k>0$ and $k=a+ib$ and examining if the solutions $a)$ even exist or $b)$ are physical solutions.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ may be complex-valued functions, $k$ can be complex. If $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be real-valued, then $k$ must be real.